# No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Getting the following exception:
`No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments`
 at

```
@{SessionValue = Session["PracticeId"].ToString();}
```

Not able to understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: It would be great if you can show us sample code

Comment: _"Not able to understand what i'm doing wrong"_ Maybe: **Not able to understand what you're doing!!!**

Comment: @user1842224 <a href='http://google.com?id=@Session["PracticeId"]'>Test</a>

Comment: I need to remove the clicked value from the session for that reason I need to assign session value in a variable

Comment: Could you show the code where you are using this `SessionValue` variable?

Comment: In view which is as follows:   @{string SessionValue = string.Empty;} @if(Session["PracticeId"] != null)
                {
                    @{SessionValue = Session["PracticeId"].ToString();}
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
@{string SessionValue = string.Empty;} 

@if(Session["PracticeId"] != null) 
{ 
    SessionValue = Session["PracticeId"].ToString();
}
```

You don't need to be putting the `SessionValue` variable assignment in `@{}` because the `if` statement is already providing you with server code context.

Comment: @user1842224, if this post helped you solve the problem you were having you might consider marking it as answer by clicking on the tick next to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work